# How to extract paches from 3D image in python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a 3D image with size: `Deep x Weight x Height` (for example: `10x20x30`, means 10 images, and each image has size `20x30`.

Given a patch size is `pd x pw x ph` (such as `pd <Deep, pw<Weight, ph<Height`), for example patch size: `4x4x4`. The center point location of the path will be: `pd/2 x pw/2 x ph/2`. Let's call the distance between time `t` and time `t+1` of the center point be `stride`, for example `stride=2`.

I want to extract the original 3D image into patches with size and stride given above. How can I do it in python? Thank you

.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to track some details in big images, in a(time,x,y) space ? Do you want to generate micro spaces ([t0-dt, t0+dt] , [x0-dx, x0+dx],[y0-dy, y0+dy]) for knowns (x0,y0,t0) ?

Comment: Actually, I do not care about time. I just want to extract the image into patch given image and patch size. The patch will scan from left to right, and deep. The procedure likes convolution but instead of computing value, I extract the patch

Answer (score 8):

Use `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`. This solution does *not* require the strides to divide the corresponding dimensions of the input stack. It even allows for overlapping patches (Just do not write to the result in this case, or make a copy.). It therefore is more flexible than other approaches:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib import stride_tricks

def cutup(data, blck, strd):
    sh = np.array(data.shape)
    blck = np.asanyarray(blck)
    strd = np.asanyarray(strd)
    nbl = (sh - blck) // strd + 1
    strides = np.r_[data.strides * strd, data.strides]
    dims = np.r_[nbl, blck]
    data6 = stride_tricks.as_strided(data, strides=strides, shape=dims)
    return data6#.reshape(-1, *blck)

#demo
x = np.zeros((5, 6, 12), int)
y = cutup(x, (2, 2, 3), (3, 3, 5))

y[...] = 1
print(x[..., 0], '\n')
print(x[:, 0, :], '\n')
print(x[0, ...], '\n')
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 0]] 

[[1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]] 

[[1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Explanation. Numpy arrays are organised in terms of strides, one for each dimension, data point [x,y,z] is located in memory at address base + stridex * x + stridey * y + stridez * z.

The `stride_tricks.as_strided` factory allows to directly manipulate the strides and shape of a new array sharing its memory with a given array. Try this only if you know what you're doing because no checks are performed, meaning you are allowed to shoot your foot by addressing out-of-bounds memory.

The code uses this function to split up each of the three existing dimensions into two new ones, one for the corresponding within block coordinate (this will have the same stride as the original dimension, because adjacent points in a block corrspond to adjacent points in the whole stack) and one dimension for the block index along this axis; this will have stride = original stride x block stride.

All the code does is computing the correct strides and dimensions (= block dimensions and block counts along the three axes).

Since the data are shared with the original array, when we set all points of the 6d array to 1, they are also set in the original array exposing the block structure in the demo. Note that the commented out `reshape` in the last line of the function breaks this link, because it forces a copy.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Could you please explain the idea to do it?

Comment: @user3051460 I've tried (see post); also I've simplified the code a tiny bit.

Answer (score 2):

the `skimage` module offer you an integrated solution with [view_as_blocks](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks). 
The source is on line.

Take care to choose  `Deep,Weight,Height`  multiple of `pd, pw, ph`, because `as_strided` do not check bounds.

Comment: The whole point of using `as_strided` is to cater for block dimensions that do _not_ divide the input dimensions. It is only `reshape` based solutions that come with this restriction.

Comment: mmmh. I am not very sure  of op's goal. It's seems to be a tracking task in a (t,x,y) space. in this case strides has not to be redifined... I will ask him.

Comment: @B.M. It is very nice lib. but what is happen if two patches overlap. It means the stride is smaller than Weight/2 or Height/2.

Comment: Perhaps `view_as_windows` can help you in this case ?

Comment: @B.M: You are right. as_strided does not check bound. I am trying with `view_as_windows`. Do you think `view_as_windows` support randomly select the patches?