# Evenly Split 3D Numpy Arays of Varying Sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a folder of 3D numpy arrays, which vary in size. What is the most efficient way to load one array and copy evenly spaced 100x100x100 chunks? I want the chunks to overlap slightly in each axis. The chunks will be saved to separate numpy arrays.

Is there a better way to do this (such as a built in numpy function) than finding array_3D.shape[0], array_3D.shape[1], array_3D.shape[2], calculating the spacing, and indexing?

Thank you

Comment: What are you going to do with the overlapping chunks?  Calculate something like the mean?  Or do something that requires each chunk to be a copy?  And roughly how big are these arrays?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42337357/7207392) help in any way?

Comment: Ok, I take it you are fine with closing this then?

Comment: I am now happy this is a duplicate. To extract the chunks, just remove the comment on the last line of the def. Thanks again.