# Find a 5x5 sliding window over an image and obtain all indices (indexes) for each window

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How I can to get the values of 5x5 window over image, Is there are any method to get all 25 indices for each window as int number or string form 0,0 0,1 0,2 to save it in text file over the original image?

Comment: What have you tried, and what didn't work about it?

Comment: I am not understand how make this command for reshape, and I need get with step 5 over the image an window 5x5 with indexes that I will save it to compare with other files that contain indexes tho get the intersection between them

Comment: Here is a similar Q for the 3D [case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42336919/7207392). It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt that to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here are a few hints to get you started. But this is basic stuff, please forgive my saying so but you should probably work through a tutorial or two.

To get a 5x5 window the straight forward way is slicing:

```
window = img[i:i+5, j:j+5]
```

here `i, j` are the coordinates of your window's top left corner and should lie between `0, 0` and `N-5, M-5` where `NxM[x3]` is the size of your image. The `x3` will be there if you have three colour channels.

To slide the window you can loop over `i` and `j` or use the trickery from the post I've linked to in the comments.

The indices you can get with `indices`:

```
np.moveaxis(np.indices((5, 5)), 0, -1) + (i, j)
```

but saving them all seems a bit wasteful, it would suffice to store `i, j, 5, 5`

Comment: Thank You for your replay, Paul Panzer