# Slicing overlapping sets of features from 2D numpy array into 3D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, keras

I am confronted with the following problem:

I have a 2D numpy array of shape `(total_samples, n_features)`. Think of total_samples as time series i.e. features recorded at every time step. I would like to reshape this 2D array into a 3D array of shape `(n_batch, n_samples, n_features)` to be used as input for a “many to one” long short term memory (LSTM) neural network (NN). I would like to be able to specify `n_samples` and `percentage_overlap` between batches as inputs to a python function that figures out how many batches or strides are possible from the available 2D array given the desired percentage_overlap and `n_samples`.

```
def create_chunks((total_samples, n_features), n_samples, overlap=.5)
    return (n_batch, n_samples, n_features)
```

Numerically, let’s say for a single feature and 4 samples:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

using `n_samples=2` and `percentage_overlap=.5` should output

```
[[[1], [2]], [[2], [3]], [[3], [4]]].
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337357/7207392) is my solution to a similar question. HTH

Comment: `[[[1], [2]], [[2], [3]], [[3], [4]]]` assumes a batch of 3 correct?

Comment: @DarkCygnus that is correct